# Android HTML in TextView Downloadable file link not working

Tags: android, html, textview

I have seen many answers on the `<a>` tag used in Android HTML.

I have a problem with `<a href='example.com/test.json' download />` which I have tried in simple HTML code and it's automatically downloading from the browser.

But when I try the same thing in Android **TextView**, It's not working and simply displaying data in the browser.

I would like to download that file using the `<a>` tag the same as the web version. Is it possible to do it?

The Sample JSON I found on the Internet and writing in `<a>` tag here.

```html
<a href="https://einvoice1-trial.nic.in/Documents/SampleJson.json" target="_blank" download>Sample File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using java code:

```
   TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
   textView.setClickable(true);
   textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   String text = "<a href='example.com/test.json' download> Download Now </a>";
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text)); 

// From API level >= 24 onwards Html.fromHtml(String source) is deprecated instead use fromHtml(String, int)
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Or in the layout XML file, inside your TextView widget attributes

```
   android:autoLink="web"
   android:linksClickable="true
```

Comment: is the url a json file?

Comment: Yes, You can check for sample I found on Internet is https://einvoice1-trial.nic.in/Documents/SampleJson.json

Comment: can  you explain to me what are you trying to achieve in a bit detail?

Comment: I want to download that file like this: https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761627/example_1.json

Comment: so, you mean instaed of opening, you want it o be downloaded.? correct?